# New Feature in Xamarin.Form with Fontawesome 5 not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I would like to use the [new feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/) in Xamarin.Forms enabling Fonts cross-platform but I can't get it to work properly.

Version Xamarin.Forms: 4.7.0.1080

Here's part of my code.

```
<Button Text="&#xf2ed;"
        FontFamily="FA5Regular"
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Delete, Source={x:Reference SongsCollectionView}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
        Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" StyleClass="Delete"/>
```

In app.xaml.cs:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf", Alias = "FA5Regular")]
[assembly: ExportFont("Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf", Alias ="FA5Solid")]
namespace eTabber
{
    public partial class App : TxfApplication
    {
        ...
```

Styling:

```
Button {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5;
}

Button.Delete {
    background-color: red;
}
```

In the solution:

[image]

It should produce a button with a trashcan (far fa-trash-alt) but it produces a rectangle.

[image]

[image]

== EDIT ==

It maybe very well possible the alias from the ExportFontAttribute (FA5Regular) should be different. I don't see it anywhere at runtime:

[image]

== EDIT ==

Decompiled with JustDecompile and I do see the fonts in the eTabber.dll:

[image]

== Edit ==

There's part of an answer [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10307#issuecomment-633605424) but can't get that to work either.

Comment: Are you facing this issue in both Android and iOS?

Comment: On Android, iOS and UWP.

Comment: Just found this comment on the article above here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10307#issuecomment-633605424 but it's not a complete answer. Where do I put what?

Comment: Downloaded the sample from here: https://github.com/jfversluis/EmbeddedFontsSample. Also does not work. Looks broken in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @PaulSinnema I check the sample code you provided. I works well on my side. Please check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/QXndDL5 What is the error for the sampe code?

Comment: Hi Wendy, You screenshot if from Android? I’m having this problem in UWP.

Comment: For UWP, I got the same thing. Let's follow the link on Github. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10307

Answer (score 0):

You have font awesome licence issue, Try with "solid" icons, many of them regular doesn't support.

https://fontawesome.com/download

You can find all icon code in a code files and information

https://github.com/matthewrdev/fa2cs

For example; Four support only Solid for free lib.

```
/// <summary>
/// fa-4 unicode value ("\u0034").
/// <para/>
/// This icon supports the following styles: Light (Pro), Regular (Pro), Solid, Duotone (Pro), Thin (Pro)
/// <para/>
/// Introduced in '6.0.0-beta1', Last Modified in '6.0.0-beta1'.
/// <para/>
/// See https://fontawesome.com/icons/4
/// </summary>
public const string Four = "\u0034";
```